# Using zip against multiple list values

Tags: python-3.7

I am stuck in my own maze here to find solution for this problem with attached screenshot table. I know I am unnecessary complicating this. But this was a way to get ans to my starting python mind.
Any help on how to solve below please? Thanks

Latest was a df converted to dict beforehand in the sheet.

Create a function which returns a list of countries in which there are still active cases, i.e. where Total Cases minus Total Deaths exceeds Recovered.

'''
def active_countries(data):

```
    x=latest['Total Cases']
    y=latest['Total Deaths']
    z=latest['Recovered']
    r=latest['Country']
    zipp=zip(x,y)
    k=list(zipp)
    i=[]
    for a,b in zip(x,y):
        s=a-b
        i.append(s)
  
    zipp1=zip(i,z,r)
    k1=list(zipp1)
    h=[]
    if c>d:
        h.append(r) if c>d else 0
```

'''
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FofbN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? This returns a list of all the countries that there are active cases.

```py
latest = {
    'Total Cases': [74187, 621, 81, 80, 63, 51],
    'Total Deaths': [2006, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    'Recovered': [14796, 17, 29, 20, 5, 16],
    'Country': ['China', 'Diamond Princess', 'Singapore', 'Japan', 'Hong Kong', 'S. Korea'],
}


def active_countries(data):
    cases = data['Total Cases']
    deaths = data['Total Deaths']
    recovered = data['Recovered']
    countries = data['Country']
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(countries)):
        if (cases[i] - deaths[i] > recovered[i]):
            ret.append(countries[i])
    return ret


print(active_countries(latest))
```

prints `['China', 'Diamond Princess', 'Singapore', 'Japan', 'Hong Kong', 'S. Korea']`

Here is your code edited

```py
latest = {
    'Total Cases': [74187, 621, 81, 80, 63, 51],
    'Total Deaths': [2006, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    'Recovered': [14796, 17, 29, 20, 5, 16],
    'Country': ['China', 'Diamond Princess', 'Singapore', 'Japan', 'Hong Kong', 'S. Korea'],
}


def active_countries(data):
    x = data['Total Cases']
    y = data['Total Deaths']
    z = data['Recovered']
    r = data['Country']
    zipp = zip(x, y)
    k = list(zipp)
    i = []
    for a, b in zip(x, y):
        s = a-b
        i.append(s)

    zipp1 = zip(i, z, r)
    k1 = list(zipp1)
    h = []
    #iterates through the zip list
    for i in k1:
        #unpacks i, _ is a placeholder for a value we don't need
        a, b, _ = i
        if (a > b):
            h.append(i)
    return h


print(active_countries(latest))
```

prints `[(72181, 14796, 'China'), (621, 17, 'Diamond Princess'), (81, 29, 'Singapore'), (79, 20, 'Japan'), (61, 5, 'Hong Kong'), (51, 16, 'S. Korea')]`

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!
Wasnt aware of the _ placeholder thing. Reading on it now.
the correct answer though would be via if (cases[i] - deaths[i] > recovered[i]):
Thank you so much again